# Add adjacent elements in a matrix using CUDA

Tags: cuda

Given an nxn matrix, I want to find the summation of adjacent elements (top, down, left, right) and replace the middle element with that sum using CUDA, ie, everything should be done in parallel.

For example, with 3 elements

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

If we take the middle element (coordinates (1,1)), the sum of adjacent elements are (2+4+6+8=)20. This should be replaced with the middle element

1 2 3

4 20 6

7 8 9

Here is the code I wrote. This code will work if n=3, and this will not work if the n is greater (eg: n=5). Please suggest me a method to generalize this code.

Please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 3
#define BLOCK_DIM 3

__global__ void matrixAdd (int *a, int *c) {
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    int index = col + row * N;

    int sum = 0;
    if (row == 1 && col == 1 && col < N && row < N) {
        sum = sum + a[index - 1];
        sum = sum + a[index + 1];
        sum = sum + a[index - 3];
        sum = sum + a[index + 3];
    }
    c[index] = sum;
}

void printMatrix(int a[N][N] )
{
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++){
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[N][N], c[N][N];
    int *dev_a, *dev_c;

    int size = N * N * sizeof(int);

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++){
            a[i][j] = rand() % 256;
        }

    printf("Matrix A\n");
    printMatrix(a);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, size);

    cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_DIM, BLOCK_DIM);
    dim3 dimGrid((N+dimBlock.x-1)/dimBlock.x, (N+dimBlock.y-1)/dimBlock.y);

    printf("dimGrid.x = %d, dimGrid.y = %d\n", dimGrid.x, dimGrid.y);

    matrixAdd<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(dev_a,dev_c);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("Matrix c\n");
    printMatrix(c);

    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_c);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is for every output element to be the sum of its top,bottom,left, and right neighbors from the input, you only have to make a small change in your code to handle arbitrary sizes, from this:

```
if (row == 1 && col == 1 && col < N && row < N) {
    sum = sum + a[index - 1];
    sum = sum + a[index + 1];
    sum = sum + a[index - 3];
    sum = sum + a[index + 3];
}
c[index] = sum;
```

to this:

```
if (row > 0 && col > 0 && col < N-1 && row < N-1 ) {  //note the change
    sum = sum + a[index - 1];
    sum = sum + a[index + 1];
    sum = sum + a[index - N];                         //note the change
    sum = sum + a[index + N];                         //note the change
    c[index] = sum;                                   //note the change
}
```

This excludes the borders, since the operation is not defined for the borders, consistent with your example code.  If you want to populate the border regions with the input data (consistent with the example you have provided in the question text, which does not match the way your example code behaves), there are a couple ways to do that.  One would be to just copy the input data to the output data before running the above modified kernel:

```
cudaMemcpy(dev_c, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```